# How to check and uncheck checkbox using change method

Tags: angular, checkbox, onchange

I want to trigger an event only when the check box is tick and then it will remove the event when the check box is unchecked. How do I do this?Currently I'm using (change) to trigger an event but this will be triggered if I check or unchecked the box.

```js
 public send(line : any){
    this.broadCastService.sendLine(line);
  }
```

```html
<div *ngFor="let line of test  ">
  <label>
    {{line.lineNumber}}
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="line" (change)="send(line)">
  </label>
```

Answer (score 0):

This kind of scenario or condition must go under ts file.  There are couple of issues in your code like it should not be `ng-model` instead `ngModel`. Looks like you have AngularJS background. Anyway here is the fix

### html

```
<div *ngFor="let line of test  ">
  <label>
    {{line.lineNumber}}
    <input type="checkbox" (change)="send($event)">
  </label>
```

### ts

```
 public send(checked: any){
    if(checked){  //send if the value is true
        this.broadCastService.sendLine(line);
    }
  }
```

> Note : checkbox will hold only true or false. You may need to get the `line` from somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

*You can do this way*

**Ts**

```
export class Line {
  lineNumber:string;
  isActive:boolean;
}

public send(event, index : number) {
    // If value is true will execute the event
    if(test[index].isActive) {  
        this.broadCastService.sendLine(test[index]);
    }
}

// Assume we have the list as "test"
let test = new Array<Line>();
```

Assume 'test' has few data's in it

**HTML**

```
<div *ngFor="let line of test;let i = index">
  <label>
    {{line.lineNumber}}
    <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="line.isActive" (change)="send($event,i)">
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[This link contains example of check and uncheck checkbox using change method](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xqtmnl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)